# Migrating from Legacy stripe checkout to the new version in codeigniter

Tags: php, jquery, stripe-payments, codeigniter-3

I am working on a project which will work as a marketplace website. I already have stripe library as an initial payment method where will receive payment from customers from the website but it seems like the old version of stripe has been upgraded and I want to adopt the new version.

```
public function stripe_payment_post()
{
    require_once(APPPATH . 'third_party/stripe/vendor/autoload.php');
    try {
        $token = $this->input->post('payment_id', true);
        $email = $this->input->post('email', true);
        $payment_amount = $this->input->post('payment_amount', true);
        $currency = $this->input->post('currency', true);
        //Init stripe
        $stripe = array(
            "secret_key" => $this->payment_settings->stripe_secret_key,
            "publishable_key" => $this->payment_settings->stripe_publishable_key,
        );
        
        \Stripe\Stripe::setApiKey($stripe['secret_key']);
        //customer
        $customer = \Stripe\Customer::create(array(
            'email' => $email,
            'source' => $token
        ));
        //charges
        $charge = \Stripe\Charge::create(array(
            'customer' => $customer->id,
            'amount' => $payment_amount,
            'currency' => $currency,
            'description' => trans("stripe_checkout")
        ));

        //add to database
        $data_transaction = array(
            'payment_method' => "Stripe",
            'payment_id' => $token,
            'currency' => $currency,
            'payment_amount' => get_price($payment_amount, 'decimal'),
            'payment_status' => $this->input->post('payment_status', true),
        );

    } catch (\Stripe\Error\Base $e) {
        $this->session->set_flashdata('error', $e->getMessage());
        $data = array(
            'status' => 0,
            'redirect' => generate_url("cart", "payment")
        );
        echo json_encode($data);
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        $this->session->set_flashdata('error', $e->getMessage());
        $data = array(
            'status' => 0,
            'redirect' => generate_url("cart", "payment")
        );
        echo json_encode($data);
    }
}
```

// Here is the client side

```
<script src="https://checkout.stripe.com/v2/checkout.js"></script>
<script>
    var handler = StripeCheckout.configure({
        key: '<?php echo $this->payment_settings->stripe_publishable_key; ?>',
        image: 'https://stripe.com/img/documentation/checkout/marketplace.png',
        locale: 'auto',
        currency: '<?php echo $currency; ?>',
        token: function (token) {
            var data = {
                'payment_id': token.id,
                'email': token.email,
                'currency': '<?php echo $currency; ?>',
                'payment_amount': '<?php echo $total_amount; ?>',
                'payment_status': 'success',
               
                'sys_lang_id': sys_lang_id
            };
            data[csfr_token_name] = $.cookie(csfr_cookie_name);
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: base_url + "stripe-payment-post",
                data: data,
                success: function (response) {
                    var obj = JSON.parse(response);
                    if (obj.result == 1) {
                        window.location.href = obj.redirect;
                    } else {
                        location.reload();
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    });
    document.getElementById('btn_stripe_checkout').addEventListener('click', function (e) {
        handler.open({
            name: '<?php echo html_escape($this->general_settings->application_name); ?>',
            description: '<?php echo trans("stripe_checkout"); ?>',
            amount: '<?php echo $total_amount; ?>'
        });
        e.preventDefault();
    });
    // Close Checkout on page navigation:
    window.addEventListener('popstate', function () {
        handler.close();
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can find documentation describing this migration here: https://stripe.com/docs/payments/checkout/migration